# Can I stop svchost.exe's "\Device\Mup NO MORE MATCHES"?

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze

I have the situation kind of similar to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/552825/what-is-the-purpose-of-frequent-i-o-operations-on-device-mup-on-windows), but worse.

Every time my computer wakes up from sleeping more than a couple of hours, it freezes for five minutes.
If you reboot the computer, you will get two minutes of the same freezes.

The freezes start only when you start being active, like typing the user password.

A typical freeze goes like this - you can move your mouse, but the screen doesn't change even if you click on something.
The window that was active becomes "Not Responding".
After some time (from 15 sec to 1 min) the clicks that you've done come into action.
You have approximately five to ten seconds of the computer responding to your actions and programs doing what they should do.
After that, the cycle repeats itself.

Based on the info from Process Monitor, the culprit is `svchost.exe` `\Device\Mup  NO MORE MATCHES`.

From the post linked above, `\Device\Mup` is related to remote files and similar stuff.
I'm OK with giving up the ability to operate files remotely if my laptop stops freezing.

I checked my hard drive with `chkdsk` and `WD Life Diagnostic` - everything nominal.
I also checked for viruses with KVRT and Malwarebytes.

Full info about this command.
Class: File System
Operation: DeviceIoControl
Result: NO MORE MATCHES
Path: \Device\Mup
Version: 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
Command line: C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNoNetwork
Control: 0x1403a4 (Device:0x14 Function:233 Method: 0)

**EDIT**:
After more than a year, the problem has occurred two more times, this time it did not stop at freezing.

I encountered the same situation with freezing, but Windows decided to BSOD in the middle of it. I rebooted the laptop. That gave me another BSOD with a different error. Luckily, the next relaunch was successful with no symptoms after that.

After several months, I was browsing sites when the hard drive suddenly produced a distinct noise that was not like anything it sounded before. It sounded like reading heads going way off course and hitting something.
After that, the computer was still working, but the hard drive became deathly silent. You could close apps, scroll what was loaded, but no drive operations were executed. Again, luckily, it rebooted successfully.

Therefore, I guess this whole `NO MORE MATCHES` thing was about the hard drive slowly dying. It's seven years old already.

Comment: Device Input and Output has to do with your motherboard, BIOS and hard disk, it could be a cable with a defect or a failing hard disk. I/O in out. DeviceIoControl has to do with calls to a driver, it can send errors, etc to the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about the hard drive slowly dying.
The freezes repeated themselves, now with the system unable to restore itself, entering a bootloop.
I managed to revive the system only with `sfc /scannow`. Nothing else worked from the standard toolkit.

The bootloop has repeated itself several days after the first one. After that, the laptop remains operational, but I rarely use it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft definition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/support-for-unc-naming-and-mup)
for MUP defines it as :

> The multiple UNC provider (MUP) is a kernel-mode component responsible for channeling all remote file system accesses using a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) name to a network redirector (the UNC provider) that is capable of handling the remote file system requests.

This seems to indicate that you have a some strange problem with network shares,
or with your network in general.

Checks that you may do :

- Undo any created network shares and verify
- Check if the problem exists when booting in Safe Mode, to see if the problem
  is caused by some installed product.